# Dynatrace Taging-JMeter

Tags: jmeter, dynatrace, apm

I would like to add `DynaTrace` tags i.e.,

`dynaTrace: PC=JMETER;NA=Transaction Name;VU=Thread Group Name`

to JMeter script on **transaction level** not **request level**.
if any one have suggestion/answer for that please help me

Answer (score 0):

In Dynatrace, you cannot tag the headers at transaction level. Instead, you can create [Business Transactions](https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT61/Usage+of+Business+Transactions).

You can use Business Transactions to track special transactions (e.g. login and buy) in the application under diagnosis. For example, you can track the number and response time of a login action for a specific user group for the application. The Business Transaction consists of a filter measure that checks for the occurrence for a specific user tag (e.g. a tagged web request measure). The default response time and count  are selected by default. The splitting measure is application, which is also the default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for simple Apache JMeter integration with Dynatrace, then have a look at the Monitoring Plugin for JMeter provided by UbikLoadPack :

- https://ubikloadpack.com/tryout.php (select **Monitoring**)

This plugin allows you to integrate with:

- [Dynatrace AppMon](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/) to record Dynatrace sessions and tag Web Requests, that's what you're looking for
- [Dynatrace One Agent](https://www.dynatrace.com/platform/oneagent/) to be able to correlate response times and other monitoring graphs and Artificial Intelligence analysis

Disclaimer : We are providers of this solution